# AWK parse month from date into variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file with the following data:-

```
2012/02/17  154.89    24.00        3.72   0.098      0.36   0.188     0.050     0.03  0.58
2012/02/18  238.16    24.00        5.72   0.098      0.56   0.188     0.050     0.04  0.79
2012/03/19  155.55    24.00        3.73   0.098      0.37   0.188     0.050     0.03  0.58
2012/03/20  186.00    24.00        4.46   0.098      0.44   0.188     0.050     0.03  0.66
2012/04/21  487.86    8.87         4.33   0.098      0.42   0.188     0.050     0.03  0.64
2012/04/22  264.32    24.00        6.34   0.098      0.62   0.188     0.050     0.04  0.85
2012/04/23  328.65    23.99        7.89   0.098      0.77   0.188     0.050     0.05  1.01
2012/04/24  155.31    24.00        3.73   0.098      0.37   0.188     0.050     0.03  0.58
2012/04/25  229.36    24.00        5.50   0.098      0.54   0.188     0.050     0.04  0.76
2012/04/26  153.45    24.00        3.68   0.098      0.36   0.188     0.050     0.03  0.58
```

I have the following AWK script, when the date field changes it prints out "diff".

```
awk '{print $1,l} NR!=1 && $1!=l {print "diff"} {l=$1}' MyFile
```

Which produces the following output:-

```
2012/02/17
2012/02/18 2012/02/17
diff
2012/03/19 2012/02/18
diff
2012/03/20 2012/03/19
diff
2012/04/21 2012/03/20
diff
2012/04/22 2012/04/21
diff
2012/04/23 2012/04/22
diff
2012/04/23 2012/04/23
2012/04/23 2012/04/23
2012/04/23 2012/04/23
2012/04/23 2012/04/23
2012/04/24 2012/04/23
diff
2012/04/25 2012/04/24
diff
2012/04/26 2012/04/25
diff
 2012/04/26
diff
```

How would i modify the script to tell it, only print out "diff" when the month in the date changes (the middle number) and not the entire date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the first field based on the separator "/". Use that result in the comparison.

```
$ awk '
> {print $1, l; split($1, m, "/");}
> NR!=1 && m[2]!=l {print "diff";}
> {l=m[2];}' MyFile
2012/02/17
2012/02/18 02
2012/03/19 02
diff
2012/03/20 03
2012/04/21 03
diff
2012/04/22 04
2012/04/23 04
2012/04/24 04
2012/04/25 04
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this should work:

```
awk -F'[ \t/]' '
{d=$1 "/" $2 "/" $3; print d, od; od = d} 
NR!=1 && $2!=l {print "diff"} 
{l=$2}' FILE
```